# multiple commands in an ansible playbook for an if statement?

Tags: ansible, yaml

I want to disable Windows defender on a windows client unless the status is already disabled.

At the moment I've divided it in 2 tasks using the register command in ansible

```
---
-hosts: all 
  become_method: runas
  tasks:
   - name: Check if WinDefend is running
     win_shell: (Get-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows Defender").DisableAntiSpyware
     register: WinDefendStatus
     become: yes
     become_user: Administrator

   - name: Turn off WinDefend
     win_shell: New-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows Defender" -Name DisableAntiSpyware -Value 1 -PropertyType DWORD -Force
     become: yes
     become_user: Administrator
     when: WinDefendStatus.stdout == "0" or ""
```

Technically this works but I'd like to have this in 1 task. The guides only show local variables or local stored facts but none about remotely gotten values.

Any idea how to do this?

Comment: It is good to see, that you try to keep your play idenpotent, but I don't think that your wish to do this with one task this is not possible for this specific issue, as long as you start writing your own module for this task. Another way might be to setup the Windefender status as a custom fact on playbook startup.

Comment: [`win_shell:`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.8/modules/win_shell_module.html) just runs PowerShell, so why not `win_shell: If ((Get-ItemProperty -Path etc etc) -eq "0") { New-ItemProperty -Path etc etc; }`?

Comment: Following @MatthewLDaniel comment, you can echo "changed" when modifying the status, echo something different in an else section, capture the output and add a `changed_when: result.stdout == "changed"`. That would be a single task totally idempotent.